# Meaning of $V(P)$ in the definition of forcing

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm trying to understand a small part of the definition of [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) on Wikipedia. I'm trying to tackle the parts of (the definition of) forcing that are easiest to understand first. I know what a countable, standard, transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is, but not much beyond that. (For example, I know why we have a countable model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but not *why* we're promised a standard, transitive one).

The definition makes reference to a class that's like an expanded version of $V$, called $V(P)$. What is $V(P)$?

Also, if we remove the restrictions on $P$ being atomless and thereby permit $P$ to be finite, what do we get when $P$ is a singleton poset or a two element poset $\{\top, \bot\}$?

Also, are there application of a class like $V(P)$ that are easier to understand than forcing itself?

---

In the notation $\{ f(x, y, z) : (y, z) \mathop. \varphi(z) \}$, I am using $y$ and $z$ as the variables being quantified over inside the set builder expression. In the above example $x$ is a free variable.

In particular, I'm confused about $V(P)$, $V^{(\mathbb{P})}$ in Wikipedia's notation, where $\mathbb{P}$ is an atomless partial order.

$V(P)$ is defined as follows.

$$ V(P) = \bigcup \{ \text{Name}_P(\alpha) : \alpha \mathop. \alpha \;\; \text{is an ordinal} \} $$

First we have a transfinite recursive definition of $\text{Name}_P$.

$$\text{Name}_P(0) = \varnothing $$
$$\text{Name}_P(\alpha + 1) = 2^{\text{Name}_P(\alpha) \times P}$$
$$\text{Name}_P(\lambda) = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} \text{Name}_P(\alpha)$$

From this definition, we can look at two special cases

- $\text{Name}_P(1) = \{ \varnothing \}$, so $\varnothing$ will eventually end up in $V(P)$.
- $\text{Name}_P(2) = 2^{\{ (\varnothing, p) : p \mathop. p \in P \}} = \{ \{ (\varnothing, p) : p \mathop. p \in P' \land P' \subset P \} : P' \mathop. P' \subset P \} $

And this kind of makes sense.

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1174805), I get the intuitive sense that $V(P)$ can be thought of as kind of like an expanded version of $V$ the universe of sets.

At this point I'm going out on a limb and seeing if I can define some elementary set-theoretic stuff in $V(P)$ that looks like familiar stuff like $\in$ and $\cup$ and $\setminus$.

So, a universe of sets has an elementhood relation, and I'd really like to define the analog of that so that $V(P)$ has a little bit more structure to it.

If I squint a little, $P$ is a partial order and kind of feels like a set of truth values.

The first problem that I run in to with that approach is that an element of $V(P)$, interpreted as a relation, associated with more than one element of the poset $P$.

That's okay, $2^P$ kind of looks like a set of truth values too.

I can now define $E : V(P) \times V(P) \to 2^P$ as follows.

$$ E(y, x) \;\;\text{probably should be}\;\; \{ p : (z, p) \mathop. (z, p) \in x \land x = y \} $$

So, the intuition is, when $y$ does occur explicitly in some pairs in $x$, and the truth value we get back is a subset of $P$.

This feels wrong somehow and it feels like I'm not asking the right questions.

Comment: Think of a $\nu\in M(P)$ as a "conditional set." It makes reference to a hypothetical subset (really, *filter*) $G\subseteq P$, and consists of data like "if $p\in G$ then I contain $17$." Crucially, we can **nest** instructions: something like "If $p\in G$ then I contain the conditional set given by [if $q\in G$ then I contain $17$]" is *also* allowed. Now if $M$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $P\in M$, given $\nu\in M(P)$ we can **evaluate** $\nu$ on a given $G\subseteq P$ ... *even if* that $G$ is not in $M$. (In this case the evaluation $\nu[G]$ also probably won't be in $M$.)

Comment: If $A$ is an atom of $\Bbb P$ and $G$ is a filter on $\Bbb P$ with $A\in G$ then $G\in M$ so $M[G]=M$, which accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have three really basic follow-up questions. Is $17$ in your example really $\hat{17} = (\hat{16}, 1) = ((\hat{15} ,1), 1) = \cdots$, so when we want to talk about an explicit ordinary set we add $1$s internally at every level? If I were working in a set theory with urelements $U$, would $\text{Name}(\varnothing)$ be $U$? How do you $M(P)$ in terms of $V(P)$ and $M$ ... Wikipedia says that $M(P)$ is a subclass of $V(P)$ but doesn't elaborate.